# how do i iterate through a series of outcomes in a json file

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have an api request that requests the past 1000 outcomes of a roulette game to verify the legitimacy of a website, and it sends back a json dict of the past 1000 outcomes. a sample of it looks like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "response": {
        "total": 1000000,
        "fetched_total": 1000,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 1000,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 6414202,
                "round_id": 6414446,
                "player_count": 8,
                "outcome": 6,
                "hash": "f5be91081cfbec6c216f1ca4c167b5ec585b1c1bd30f2e1cdb90ca0706f15f1e",
                "secret": "df2b069639eb81085a90d46d8593404d739e9a6cff8ce5630e6d39e8bf5fed8b",
                "secret_badge": 130,
                "secret_index": 85549,
                "game_opened_timestamp": "2022-08-08 17:17:09"
            },
            {
                "id": 6414201,
                "round_id": 6414445,
                "player_count": 8,
                "outcome": 12,
                "hash": "753eeb83ff534fdc12441eb7fb2f34ae7678d06355d10a2dd91f54102ef74fc1",
                "secret": "f5be91081cfbec6c216f1ca4c167b5ec585b1c1bd30f2e1cdb90ca0706f15f1e",
                "secret_badge": 130,
                "secret_index": 85550,
                "game_opened_timestamp": "2022-08-08 17:16:45"
            }
       ]
  },
"cache": false,
"error_code":0
}
```

i have a program that requests it and prints out the entire json dict, but i just want it to print out the outcome of each game. for example this one would print out 6, then 12.

i was thinking i could use a for loop to iterate through but I wasn't sure how

my program current looks like this in python

```
import requests
url = "https://www.wtfskins.com/api/v1/rouletteroundhistory/?limit=1000&offset=0"
response = requests.get("https://www.wtfskins.com/api/v1/rouletteroundhistory/?limit=1000&offset=0")
file = response.json()
#print(file)
print(file['response']['data'][0]['outcome'])
input()
```

Comment: `for game in file['response']['data']: print(game['outcome'])`

Comment: You could do this using _comprehensions_ or a for-loop.